# Django get_or_create, how to say commit=False

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have this model:

```
class SocialGroupMembers(models.Model):
    social_group = models.ForeignKey(SocialGroup, related_name="members")
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

If I do:

```
obj, created = SocialGroupMembers.objects.get_or_create(
        social_group=social_group, profile=profile)
    # this will give integrity error that added_by can not be null
```

I don't want to include `added_by` field in filter criteria. I want to save `added_by` field later. Something like `commit=False` to tell Django that I have plans to add more fields later:

```
obj, created = SocialGroupMembers.objects.get_or_create(commit=False,
        social_group=social_group, profile=profile)
if created:
    obj.added_by = request.user
    obj.save()
else:
    #do something
```

I know there are alternatives e.g. I can use `ObjectDoesNotExist`. But Is there any way to achieve the desired functionality in `get_or_create`?

The reason I want to exclude the `added_by` field is because may be another user has already added another user Profile.

Comment: Adding commit=False to get_or_create is a good idea. Perhaps you might like to float the suggestion on the django-developers mailing list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a `defaults` argument you can pass to `get_or_create` to populate this data for newly created objects which are not used in the filtering:

```
defaults = {'added_by': request.user}
obj, created = SocialGroupMembers.objects.get_or_create(
        social_group=social_group, profile=profile, defaults=defaults)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create